# sonar-maven-plugin with two-step build process

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project that needs to be compiled in two steps: first some modules, then the remaining modules (for the record, the project uses Eclipse Tycho to build and uses both "pom-first" and "manifest-first" modules that cannot be mixed in the same reactor build. Cf. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts).
I then use 2 maven profiles to split the modules, and I compile the whole project with something like:

`mvn clean install -Pprofile1`

`mvn clean install -Pprofile2`

I would like to analyze this project using sonar-maven-plugin, but with a single SonarQube project. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you explain that: `modules that cannot be mixed in the same reactor build` ? Why not?

Comment: It's explained in this link: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts